# When does normalization happen in the perspective projection matrix

Tags: mathematics, matrix, projection

I am currently watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqNcqBdrNyI&t=1162s) where the instructor shows how the perspective project matrix is actually derived.

There are a few things that I am still unclear of. Firstly he says we need to normalize the coordinates between -1 and 1. However I do not understand where that happens or how that even happens.

I understand what normalization means however in this context I am completely lost.

Secondly I do not understand how the multiplying \$1/tan(θ)\$ with both the x and y coordinates helps.

The only part that I understood was multiplying that aspect ratio with the x coordinate.

If anyone could clear this up I would appreciate it.